# dplyr/dt summarise if columns are not blank/NA and paste?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

My data is:

```
Name        House   Street      Apt City    Postal  Phone
DUMA PAUL   2030    GREEN ROAD      DESERT  Z0K2K1  999-577-3789
DUNN S              GREEN ROAD      DESERT  Z0K2K1  999-577-3256
FERGUSON BOB        GREEN ROAD      DESERT  Z0K2K1  999-577-3771
FITSCHEN A  3989    GREEN ROAD      DESERT  Z0K2K1  999-577-3557
BLACK CARY  2079    GREEN ROAD      DESERT  Z0K2K1  999-577-3779
BLACK RUTH  2079    GREEN ROAD      DESERT  Z0K2K1  999-577-3779
```

I am trying to compare Names (dynamically, and the data is sorted by House), if equal AND house # is equal, concatenate the respective two phone numbers with "OR" and delete the row thats not concatenated and concatenate the names with "AND"

I am using:

```
 data <- data %>%
    group_by(House, Street, Apt, City, Postal) %>%
    summarise(Name = first(paste(Name, collapse = ", AND ")), Phone = 
    paste(unique(Phone), collapse = " OR ")) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(Street, desc(House)) %>%
    select(colnames(dataset)) %>%
    filter(!Phone %in% dnc$`Home Phone`)
```

**The problem**: with the above dplyr, I am concatenating if the House is NA (or blank, I made my NA's blank) and the Apt is NA(or "") and I do not want to. So using the code above, I would have

```
  Name                      House   Street  Apt City    Postal  Phone
  DUNN S, AND FERGUSON BOB      GREEN ROAD      DESERT  Z0K2K1  9995773256 
  OR 9995773772
  DUMAS PAUL                2030    GREEN ROAD   DESERT Z0K2K1  
  9995773789
  BLACK CARY, AND BLACK RUTH 2079   GREEN ROAD   DESERT Z0K2K1  
  9995773779
  FITSCHEN A                 3989   GREEN ROAD   DESERT Z0K2K1  
  9995773556
```

With the above, notice DUNN S, AND FERGUSON BOB are now together. I do not want that.

dput (sorry if not helpful):

```
  list(structure(list(X__1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Name = c("DUMAS 
   PAUL", 
   "DUNN S", "FERGUSON BOB", "FITSCHEN A", "BLACK CARY", "BLACK RUTH"
   ), House = c("2030", NA, NA, "3989", "2079", "2079"), Street = c("GREEN 
   ROAD", 
   "GREEN ROAD", "GREEN ROAD", "GREEN ROAD", "GREEN ROAD", "GREEN ROAD"
   ), Apt = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), City = c("DESERT", "DESERT", 
   "DESERT", "DESERT", "DESERT", "DESERT"), Prov = c("ZK", "ZK", 
   "ZK", "ZK", "ZK", "ZK"), Postal = c("Z0K2K1", "Z0K2K1", "Z0K2K1", 
   "Z0K2K1", "Z0K2K1", "Z0K2K1"), Phone = c("999-577-3789", "999-577-3256", 
    "999-577-3772", "999-577-3556", "999-577-3779", "999-577-3779"
    ), `Last Appear Date` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("X__1", 
    "Name", "House", "Street", "Apt", "City", "Prov", "Postal", "Phone", 
    "Last Appear Date"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names 
     = c(NA, 
    -6L)))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `DT[, {...}, by=]`, you can write pretty much anything. In this case, an `if... else` works:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
DT = as.data.table(data)

DT[, 
  if (!(is.na(House) & is.na(Apt))) 
    .(
      Name = Name %>% paste(collapse = ", AND "), 
      Phone = Phone %>% unique %>% paste(collapse = " OR ")
    )
  else
    .(Name, Phone)
, by=.(House, Street, Apt, City, Postal)]

   House          Street Apt   City Postal                       Name        Phone
1:  2030 GREEN \n   ROAD  NA DESERT Z0K2K1            DUMAS \n   PAUL 999-577-3789
2:    NA      GREEN ROAD  NA DESERT Z0K2K1                     DUNN S 999-577-3256
3:    NA      GREEN ROAD  NA DESERT Z0K2K1               FERGUSON BOB 999-577-3772
4:  3989      GREEN ROAD  NA DESERT Z0K2K1                 FITSCHEN A 999-577-3556
5:  2079      GREEN ROAD  NA DESERT Z0K2K1 BLACK CARY, AND BLACK RUTH 999-577-3779
```

Something similar can be done with `dplyr::do`, probably.

You don't have to use magrittr here; it's just my preference for the `paste` parts. You might also want to add a `%>% sort` step to those pipelines (so lists of phones and names are always ascending).

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's no "pretty" solution for this problem, it's a processing that doesn't fit nicely in dplyr's workflow. One workaround is to somehow identify uniquely the houses with empty data. This way, they won't be grouped together. One way to do this is to put "#row_number" when `House` is empty. Now they won't be grouped together, since every empty row will have a different number. After the processing, you can simply replace the values starting with an `#` with an empty string or a `NA`.

```
data %>%
  mutate(House = if_else(House == "" | is.na(House), paste0("#", row_number()), House)) %>%
  # does the processing... %>%
  mutate(House = if_else(startsWith(House, "#"), "", House))
```